# Como acessar um objeto do typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estou tentando acessar um banco de dados no `firestore` com este `getAlldocuments`:

```
getAllDocuments(collection: string): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.collection(collection)
          .get()
          .then((querySnapshot) => {
              let arr = [];

              querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                  var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
                  obj.$key = doc.id
                  console.log(obj)
                  arr.push(obj);

              });

              if (arr.length > 0) {
                  console.log("Document data:", arr);
                  resolve(arr);
              } else {
                  console.log("No such document!");
                  resolve(null);
              }
          })
          .catch((error: any) => {
              reject(error);
          });
  });
```

}

Os dados originais estão no documento firestore ghFinancas no seguinte formato:

```
data: string
desc:  string
valor: number
tipo: string
```

Meu problema é que o resultado do getAllDocuments gera um objeto e eu não estou conseguindo acessar os elementos deste objeto para jogar pro meu HTML.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda antecipadamente